# Curl localhost connection refused

Tags: curl, cmd, get, localhost, fastapi

I am trying to run this command in git bash:

```sh
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

or

```sh
curl localhost:8000/
```

but I receive this error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000 after 2043 ms: Connection refused
```

tried to npx kill-port 8000 but it didn't solve the issue.
when I use the following command, it works without issue on the same port of  http://127.0.0.1:8000:

```sh
python -m uvicorn main:app
```

unfortunately, I need to have this with curl command.

Comment: .. but the python command runs a _server_ on the port; curl attempts to retrieve content from the port. Exactly what is your problem? What does npx kill-port have to do with fastapi?

Comment: by talking about npx kill-port 8000, I wanted to say the error is not due to not having port used by another process.

Comment: My problem is that when I want to run my  fastapi locally, I receive a connection refused error with the curl command that I mentioned above.

Comment: You say that "when i use the following command it works", and then show how you start FastAPI. I'm not sure what you expect to happen if you don't run the command to start uvicorn with your application?

Comment: @MatsLindh yeah, that's correct. both "curl localhost:8000/" and "python -m uvicorn main:app" should do the same thing but the curl command gives me the connection refused error.

Comment: Ran this command: netsh http show servicestate. port 8000 is not in the output

Comment: No, they should _not_ do the same thing. One starts a Python fastapi server, the other makes a request to this server. One creates a server that listens for connections (`uvicorn`), while the other makes requests to a server (`curl`). The `curl` command does not replace the `uvicorn` command; they do not do the same thing.

Comment: @MatsLindh so based on your explanation, when the curl command doesn't work, it means that there is no localhost:8000/ that curl can request on it.
Do you know how can I recover localhost:8000/? I was using it 2 days ago without error. Installed something which I cannot remember exactly and this error shows up after that.

Comment: When it can't connect to 127.0.0.1:8000, that means that there is no server running on 127.0.0.1:8000 (for example, your uvicorn process is not running). Why that is not running depends on how you used to run it, and whether you had a process manager handling it - i.e. how do you normally start your server?

Comment: You were right! the issue was that I wasn't creating a server and I was expecting to see results with Curl command.
Thanks @MatsLindh

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is that I needed to create a server with uvicorn then curl a request. Curl request is just for having a request on an existing server. Uvicorn is the one that creates the server and curl does the requests.